# Camel with rabbitmq - Misspelt queue name

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq

Today, I tried to simulate a scenario where in the camel "to" tag I supplied a mis-spelt queue name(which was not there) Camel or RabbitMq instead of throwing an exception back continued to finish the route flow.
Intrgigued I did write a sample program to send a message using "channel.basicPublish" with a wrong queue name. I never got any exception thrown back from rabbit mq client.

however if the exchange name was wrong, I did get an exception back. Is this expected behaviour? 
I tried adding return listener, confirm listener,exception handler, etc., but none of them got invoked.
Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages are published to **exchanges**, so the exchange must be there when publishing messages. At publish time RabbitMQ doesn't care about queues, unless the `mandatory` flag is provided, or the channel is in confirm mode.